# Real Algebraic Numbers is Real Closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to show that if $R$ is a real closed field, then its subfield of elements which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ is real closed.

Let $R$ be real closed. Let $R_0$ be the subfield of elements which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. If $a \in R_0$ and $a>0$, then $\exists b \in R$ such that $b^2=a$. This is by definition of a real closed field. I am not sure why this implies $b$ is algebraic over $R_0$. Can someone please explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you started the proof: you want to prove that $R_0$ is real closed, so you have to prove that:

- Any positive element of $R_0$ has a root which lies in $R_0$, if $a>0$ is an algebraic number then there exist $P$ such that $P(a)=0$ consider $Q(x)=P(x^2)$ then if $b^2=a$ we have $Q(b)=0$ hence $b\in R_0$.
- Any odd-degree polynomial with coefficients in $R_0$ has a root in $R_0$: Let $P$ be an odd degree polynomial with coefficients in $R_0$ which has a solution root $R$, and because every root of a polynomial with algebraic coefficient is algebraic the $P$ has a root in $R_0$

I will let you do the second part.

Comment: How do you know there exists such a $Q(x)$?

Comment: I took $Q(x)=P(x^2)$ where $P(x)$ is the polynomial such that $P(a)=0$

Comment: Interesting, so for the second part you don't rely on the fact that the polynomial $P$ has odd degree.

Comment: we used it, It has **odd degree** implies that **it has a root** in $R$ and after we need just to prove that this root lies in $R_0$